# jquery popup: Getting button to open url

Tags: jquery, button, popup, bpopup

I have a simple popup which includes a button which I want to have open a Url. As coded, the button is not active and I have been unable to find the right code to enable this action.

Basic jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() {   

            var id = '#dialog';

            $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
            $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.4);  

            var winH = $(window).height();
            var winW = $(window).width();

            $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
            $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

            $(id).fadeIn(5000);     

            $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        });     
    });
```

The code for the key button is:

```
     <div id="content">
        <a class="button green" href="http://www.google.com">Goto Url</a>
     </div>
```

To activate the button I added script:

```
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
         content:'iframe', 
        contentContainer:'#content',
         loadUrl:'' 
          });
```

This script does not activate the button

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1):

You probably for got to call jQuery function, `('element_to_pop_up')` should be `$('element_to_pop_up')` also if it is id prefix it with `#`, and if it is class prefix it with `.` (dot)

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        content:'iframe', 
        contentContainer:'.content',
        loadUrl:'' 
         });
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you Adil, with your correction it works perfectly

Comment: I was too premature, the correction made the popup work but the button is not active. Where exactly does the prefix # or . go? <div id="content">
        <a class="button green" href="http://www.google.com">Goto Url</a>
     </div>